# jQuery libraries, noConflict and issues with other files (webflow.js)

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issues using multiples jQuery libraries and particularly the webflow.js

So…

```
<script src="jquery222.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">var jquery222 = jQuery.noConflict( true );</script>

<script src="webflow.js"></script>
```

No matter the order, even if I change it does not work.

And for the file (webflow.js) I´m wrapping all inside

```
(function( $ ) {

})(jquery222)
```

I tried changing as well, inside the webflow.js ALL the jQuery with jquery222.

However, I can't do it work. Can anyone take a look particularly to the *.js file...?

UPDATE:
Console error

```
TypeError: r is undefined
<anonymous>
 webflow.js:16
t()
 webflow.js:9
<anonymous>
 webflow.js:9
<anonymous>
 webflow.js:9
t()
 webflow.js:9
<anonymous>
 webflow.js:16
t()
 webflow.js:9
<anonymous>
 webflow.js:9
t()
 webflow.js:9
<anonymous>
 webflow.js:9
<anonymous>
 webflow.js:9
<anonymous>
 webflow.js:1
 webflow.js:16:59224
```

But it disappears when I just use one library (and I can´t because the CMS is using an old jQuery library by default). So the issue must be related to the noConflict use.

Comment: What "does not work"?  What issue are you having?  What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: Pasting the minified version of `webflow.js` does not help us solve this question, so I edited it out.

Comment: Do you have a non-minified version of webflow.js? Debugging the minified file isn't easy.

Comment: In the non-minified version of `webflow.js` (found at https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/55de95401f19df505cc6c89d/js/webflow.6ae5c75d3.js not sure how long this link will last), there's line at the top: `var $ = window.jQuery;` (the minified version may replace `$` with something else).   So, your wrapping it in a function does *nothing* since it resets `$` to `window.jQuery`.

Comment: Start by describing your problem from the beginning. Why do you need two versions of jquery, what two versions do you need, how are you including them in your page, etc. As it is it is very unclear what order you would actually need due to not knowing what code needs what jquery version. Fixing a jquery version conflict is relatively easy, and often doesn't even need $.noConflict.

Comment: @KevinB: For example, he could load his version (and its `noConflict`) *after* the webview one.

Comment: Given what's in your question, you don't need $.noConflict, and can simply use `(function ($) {...}(jQuery))` in webflow.js and it would work, assuming the rest of your code that needs the older jquery comes after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments by @RocketHazmat about how `webflow.js` sets an internal copy of `window.jQuery`:

> In the non-minified version of webflow.js (found at https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/55de95401f19df505cc6c89d/js/webflow.6ae5c75d3.js not sure how long this link will last), there's line at the top: `var $ = window.jQuery;` (the minified version may replace `$` with something else). So, your wrapping it in a function does nothing since it resets `$` to `window.jQuery`.

and keeping in mind that you want the older version (prepopulated in the page and outside your control) of jQuery available to the document, it seems like you'd need to do this:

```
<script src="jquery222.js"></script>
<script src="webflow.js"></script>
<script>
  var jquery222 = jQuery.noConflict( true );
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that wrapping the entire webflow file inside (function( $ ) {})(jquery222) but it did not work :(

Comment: @Peter Because of the way `webflow.js` makes its copy of `windows.jQuery`, doing that wouldn't accomplish anything. Additionally, if you follow the code I've provided, doing that is unnecessary.

Comment: Yo were right, @Ouroborus. Thanks a lot. Another new thing learned. You made my day :D